# Controlling YouTube videos on the actual YouTube site with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I've looked around at the YouTube API and various document functions to grab the video player button to stop and start videos with JavaScript.

However, YouTube's way of modifying history state seems to always result in my`document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button ytp-button')[0].click();` to run before the new video is loaded.

My goal is to pause a new youtube video when loaded.

Are there any solutions around this, something like an `onComplete` method to wait until the new content is updated?

I'm not using JQuery, and not intending to embed the video.

Only React and just plain Javascript! Thanks!

Solution: 
Set a set timeout with setTimeout(function, time); and just wait it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Using setTimeout(()=>{//Function goes here}, //time to wait in ms)

---

**Original Answer:**
You could use something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button ytp-button').length
```

to check the existence of the element. I guess you could implement a polling-function with `setTimeOut()` to check while the page is loading and act accordingly once the button loads. Alternatively, you could use a simple `document.onload = ()=>{//do stuff here}` or `DOMContentLoaded` to wait until the whole page has loaded. Hope that helped.

Comment: YouTube loads pages once, and each navigation is a state history change. On Load would only be called on the initial refresh of a page. I would already have the instance of the youtube player, however, it's just the timing of when it gets played that's really the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I checked what you mean. Maybe wrap your function around a fixed timeout?

Comment: Glad to hear that, I modify the answer so it's more visible.